# String.Substring weirdness

Tags: c#, string, substring

Ok so I've been awake too long. Going mad. Please someone tell me why this doesn't work. A string such as "201212120600" when passed into `Substring(0,4)` returns "201" not "2012". My brain is melting.

```
    private DateTime StringToDateTimeUTC(String s)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        String syear = s.Substring(0, 4);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(syear);

        int year = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, 4));
        int month = int.Parse(s.Substring(4, 2));
        int day = int.Parse(s.Substring(6, 2));
        int hour = int.Parse(s.Substring(8, 2));
        int minute = int.Parse(s.Substring(10, 2));
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return dt;
    }
```

The output is:

> 201212120600
>
> 201

Comment: because it doesn't. outputs a datetime that is correct, given "201212120600"

Comment: It does not. The problem is definitely not in this code.

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with DateTime - that comes later. I really am seeing the string "201" being returned from s.Substring(0,4).

Comment: Your mistake is elsewhere. Try running one line a time (F10) and using watch and immediate window to debug.

Comment: Tried rebuilding. Restarting VisualStudio. Might try sleeping next.

Comment: Why are you expecting the year at the end, its at the start "2012|12|12|0600"

Comment: @sa_ddam213 he doesn't. Why do you think so?

Comment: i know the year is at the start. That's what substring(0,4) should give me

Comment: I can't reproduce your results (with regard to `SubString(0, 4)`) returning `201`) in a quick test app.

Comment: (Most "bugs" in a language/runtime library are bugs in user code .. without *a minimal test-case* there is no reproduction and thus no movement of the burden-of-proof. Go back to the initial assumption/conclusion until such a case can be generated. The string `" 201"` may generate the observed output as well as perhaps other invisible/whitespace characters.)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you actually have a space in your string:

```
string s = " 201212120600";

Console.WriteLine(s);
String syear = s.Substring(0, 4);
Console.WriteLine(syear);

int year = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, 4));
Console.WriteLine(year);
```

Output:

```
 201212120600
 201
201
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Defo time to sleep.

Comment: @flobadob: Note also that in Unicode, there are some space characters that are "zero width" and therefore do not show up when you display them. In particular, the Unicode Byte Order Mark, which often comes at the beginning of files and therefore comes at the beginning of strings, is a zero-width space.

Answer (score 5):

When I paste this code into VS and run it, I get the expected output:

```
201212120600
2012
```

Note that you can achieve this same goal much easier by using `DateTime.ParseExact()`:

```
// using System.Globalization;
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    s,
    "yyyyMMddHHmm",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

... will set `dt` to the same thing you're returning.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're just doing this for fun, there is already a .NET function to do what you want;

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("201212120600", "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - but I had a leading space. Will revert to this method again.

Comment: Sounds like the same reason you are seeing '201' as output from your own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The string your passing in must be incorrect as the method you provided works fine

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted, I was simply showing his code WORKING.

Comment: I dunno. I'm grateful for all the replies - works now.

Answer (score 1):

How are you getting the string being inputted into the function?

My guess would be that whatever source you're getting it from is introducing hidden characters within the string. Try capturing the string then copy pasting it into something that shows hidden characters like Notepad++.